# Allow bing to Index WordPress site without flooding the server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, bots, http-status-code-503

I have a heavily visited WordPress site, on a strong ubuntu / nginx server with lots of RAM, and the DB is on a separate server, with varnish set up to cache web requests, as well as DB caching on the DB server.

The site runs smoothly, and can serve to over 5000 users simultaneously (according to Google analytics).

The problem is that occasionally we have search engines crawling the site, with a large amount of hits at once.

The site continues to function, but while the crawling is happening - it is impossible to login to the back-end. We get a 503 error - Service Unavailable.

I blocked the bots in the server config file, but we really ARE interested in the search engines indexing our site.

How do eat my cake and have it too?

Thanks

Comment: you can add set delay for certain or all crawler bots your robots.txt. https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2009/08/10/crawl-delay-and-the-bing-crawler-msnbot

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I'm trying it out now. Right now it looks like it's actually helping.